# JVM not starting up on running java program in Valgrind

Tags: java, valgrind

I am running a java program under Valgrind to check memory leaks in 32 bit Red hat Linux. While i execute the program using valgrind, JVM is not starting up throwing the below exception.

```
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Could not reserve enough space for object heap
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

My environment is

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)

java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)

valgrind-3.6.0
```

I was able to run the same program without Valgrind successfully.The command used is

```
valgrind  -v --smc-check=all --tool=memcheck --leak-check=yes --show-reachable=yes --leak-check=full --freelist-vol=100000000 --log-file=log.txt java -d32 -classpath "./bin:./lib/*" -Djava.library.path=/home/jni test.TestMain
```

Am I missing any thing here?

Comment: Java used garbage collection, why do you want to check for memory leaks? Memory leaks where?

Comment: My program involves JNI integration which has to be tested for memory leaks. But the issue seems to be JVM startup with Valgrind with a simple java program. I am not sure is this a bug already?

Comment: Can you try adding `-Xms1024m -Xmx1024m` after `java` on your command line?

Comment: @JosefN I know that it cannot, but using valgrind on Java code would be a mistake ... (there *are* java profilers).

Comment: Hi Elliott, I tried setting the heap memory size but the result is same, though there are enough memory available in the machine. # free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:         15101       1905      13195          0        148       1519
-/+ buffers/cache:        238      14863
Swap:        17279          0      17279

Comment: sorry my bad, I believed that valgrind is actually Java profiler, going to delete my stupid comment